# Constructor overloading in Java - best practice

Tags: java, constructor, overloading, constructor-overloading

There are a few topics similar to this, but I couldn't find one with a sufficient answer.

I would like to know what is the best practice for constructor overloading in Java. I already have my own thoughts on the subject, but I'd like to hear more advice.

I'm referring to both constructor overloading in a simple class and constructor overloading while inheriting an already overloaded class (meaning the base class has overloaded constructors).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 184):

While there are no "official guidelines" I follow the principle of KISS and DRY. Make the overloaded constructors as simple as possible, and the simplest way is that they only call this(...). That way you only need to check and handle the parameters once and only once.

```
public class Simple {

    public Simple() {
        this(null);
    }

    public Simple(Resource r) {
        this(r, null);
    }

    public Simple(Resource r1, Resource r2) {
        // Guard statements, initialize resources or throw exceptions if
        // the resources are wrong
        if (r1 == null) {
            r1 = new Resource();
        }
        if (r2 == null) {
            r2 = new Resource();
        }

        // do whatever with resources
    }

}
```

From a unit testing standpoint, it'll become easy to test the class since you can put in the resources into it. If the class has many resources (or collaborators as some OO-geeks call it), consider one of these two things:

### Make a parameter class

```
public class SimpleParams {
    Resource r1;
    Resource r2;
    // Imagine there are setters and getters here but I'm too lazy 
    // to write it out. you can make it the parameter class 
    // "immutable" if you don't have setters and only set the 
    // resources through the SimpleParams constructor
}
```

The constructor in Simple only either needs to split the `SimpleParams` parameter:

```
public Simple(SimpleParams params) {
    this(params.getR1(), params.getR2());
}
```

…or make `SimpleParams` an attribute:

```
public Simple(Resource r1, Resource r2) {
    this(new SimpleParams(r1, r2));
}

public Simple(SimpleParams params) {
    this.params = params;
}
```

### Make a factory class

Make a factory class that initializes the resources for you, which is favorable if initializing the resources is a bit difficult:

```
public interface ResourceFactory {
    public Resource createR1();
    public Resource createR2();
}
```

The constructor is then done in the same manner as with the parameter class:

```
public Simple(ResourceFactory factory) {
    this(factory.createR1(), factory.createR2());
}
```

### Make a combination of both

Yeah... you can mix and match both ways depending on what is easier for you at the time. Parameter classes and simple factory classes are pretty much the same thing considering the `Simple` class that they're used the same way.

Comment: I've noticed in this as well as other examples that the constructor definitions are written order of which uses the least to the most arguments in the constructor call. Is this standard Java style? Why?:

In my opinion it would make sense to do it the opposite way that way you the first constructor definition you should see is the one that has all the details.

Comment: @JosieThompson This is not defined in any standard as far as I know. I agree that having the full constructor first is useful to quickly see all of a method's parameters; ordering them by argument count, however, lets you follow the overloaded calls down the page which can feel more natural when you consider how we read and write code.

Comment: it is possible to have multiple constructors with 1 parameter of different type on each one? Like - new Object(int aa) / new Objec(String bb) ?

Answer (score 75):

I think the best practice is to have **single primary constructor** to which the overloaded constructors refer to by calling `this()` with the relevant parameter defaults. The reason for this is that it makes it much clearer what is the *constructed state* of the object is - really you can think of the primary constructor as the *only real constructor*, the others just delegate to it

One example of this might be `JTable` - the primary constructor takes a `TableModel` (plus column and selection models) and the other constructors call this primary constructor.

For subclasses *where the superclass already has overloaded constructors*, I would tend to assume that it is reasonable to treat any of the parent class's constructors as *primary* and think it is perfectly legitimate not to have a single primary constructor. For example,when extending `Exception`, I often provide 3 constructors, one taking just a `String` message, one taking a `Throwable` cause and the other taking both. Each of these constructors calls `super` directly.

Comment: I think "already overloaded classes" meant that the base class has several overloaded constructors.

Comment: I've modified my answer from this clarification

Comment: I agree about the first part, but not about the second part of inheriting an already overloaded class:
Let's say i'm inheriting Exception to a new class where I want that the Exception's string will begin with 'bla' - meaning I should validate it in the constructors receiving the String. In case I don't call a primary constructor like in the base class, I have to replicate the code of this validation.

Comment: I think this is unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: @Tom - there are a few occasions when I deviate from this practice but I always think carefully when doing so as I believe that not having a single *primary* constructor is a good indicator of a confused class design.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a very complex class with a lot of options of which only some combinations are valid, consider using a Builder.  Works very well both codewise but also logically.

The Builder is a nested class with methods only designed to set fields, and then the ComplexClass constructor only takes such a Builder as an argument.

---

Edit:  The ComplexClass constructor can ensure that the state in the Builder is valid.  This is very hard to do if you just use setters on ComplexClass.

Comment: Very much agree use the builder pattern, over loaded constructors like the OP is really bad idea as it fail the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the kind of classes as not all classes are created equal.

As general guideline I would suggest 2 options:

- For **value & immutable** classes (Exception, Integer, DTOs and such) use **single primary constructor** as suggested in above answer
- For everything else (session beans, services, mutable objects, JPA & JAXB entities and so on) use **default constructor only** with sensible defaults on all the properties so it can be used without additional configuration

Answer (score 0):

Constructor overloading is like method overloading. Constructors can be overloaded to create objects in different ways.

The compiler differentiates constructors based on how many arguments are present in the constructor and other parameters like the order in which the arguments are passed.

For further details about java constructor, please visit https://tecloger.com/constructor-in-java/