# Python: **kargs instead of overloading?

Tags: python, design-patterns, overloading

I have a conceptual Python design dilemma.

Say I have a `City` class, which represents a city in the database. The `City` object can be  initialized in two ways:

1. An integer (actually, an ID of an existing city in a database)
2. A list of properties (`name`, `country`, `population`, ...), which will generate a new city in the database, and retrieve its ID.

This means that the City object will always have an ID - either the initialized ID or a newly-created ID derived from the database.

The classic Java approach would [overload the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182153/constructor-overloading-in-java-best-practice) - One constructor would get a single `int`parameter, and the other would get numerous strongly-typed parameters.

#### I've failed to find an elegant way to do it in Python:

- I can create a base class with a single method `get_city_id`, and derive `CityFromID` and
  `CityFromNewData` from it, but that's a lot of effort to work around this language lacuna.
- Using class methods [seems awkward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141545/overloading-init-in-python).
- Using a constructor with a long list of parameters is also awkward: I'd put both city id and the alternatives, and verify within the method that that only a specific subset have values.

Using `**kargs` seems very inelegant, because the signature of the constructor does not clearly state the required input parameters, and docstrings just ain't enough:

```
class City(object):
    def __init__(self, city_id=None, *args, **kargs):
        try:
            if city_id==None:
                self.city_id=city_id
            else:
                self.city_name=kargs['name']
        except:
            error="A city object must be instanciated with a city id or with"+\
            " full city details."
            raise NameError(error)
```

Is there a Pythonic, elegant solution to constructor overloading?

Adam

Comment: I think that the use of class methods here is actually quite elegant. What makes them feel awkward to you?

Comment: Can you post an answer with an elegant class method solution to this one?

Comment: The Pythonic Way of overloading constructors is, in fact, factory classmethods. EoghanM's answer is such an elegant solution. It correctly separates the *creation* of a new City using its properties, from the *reinstantiation* of a City using a previously assigned id. It makes no sense to *construct* a City based on an id - the id is assigned to a City once it has been created. How does this feel awkward to you? I have also tried the `*args,**kwargs` figure-it-out-in-the-init-method-based-on-the-number-and-type-of-arguments approach, but over time I've settled on the classmethod as the best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
class City(object):
   def __init__(self, name, description, country, populations):
      self.city_name = name
      # etc.

   @classmethod
   def from_id(cls, city_id):
       # initialise from DB
```

Then you can do normal object creation:

```
 >>> c = City('Hollowberg', '', 'Densin', 3)
 >>> c.id
 1233L

 >>> c2 = City.from_id(1233)
```

~~~~~~

Also you might want to check out [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) (and [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki)) for nicer ways to do these things

Answer (score 4):

There is a design pattern called [Data Access Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object) that is usually used in your case. According to it you should separate fetching and creation of data objects in two classes City and CityDAO:

```
class City:

    def __init__(self, name, country):
        self.name = name
        self.country = country 


class CityDAO:

    def fetch(self, id):
        return query(...)

    def insert(self, city):
        query(...)
```

Comment: +1 Loading from the DB and the actual class don't belong on the same object in the first place. After loading the data there are many good ways so create a City instance.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the class (factory) method is the best one because already the method name states explicitly what is done. Two free-standing functions would also be fine:

```
def load_existing_city(id):
    ...
def create_new_city(name, population, ...):
    ...
```

Comment: Basically, I'll initialize an object and then call the "Real constructor". It's possible, but a very ugly replacement for constructor overloading!

Comment: Sometimes I miss overloading, too, but I think that the disadvantages outweigh the advantages in dynamic languages like Python. Python allows you to refer to the function *f* just by typing `f`—something that would be impossible if *f* could be overloaded.