# Defining Constructor Overloading in java

Tags: java

What is Constructor Overloading and how can i achieve that in java using an example?

Comment: It is already answered [Constructor overloading in Java - best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182153/constructor-overloading-in-java-best-practice)

Comment: http://www.leepoint.net/JavaBasics/oop/oop-45-constructor-overloading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example

```
class MyClass{

    public MyClass(){
        System.out.println("Constructor without parameters");
    }

    public MyClass(int a){
        //overloaded constructor
        System.out.println("Constructor with 'a' parameter");
    }

}
```

You can create multiple "versions" of the class constructor. This is the meaning of method overload. You can overload almost any method of a Java class.

Take a look to official Java tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

More information on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html and http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=284

Comment: Thank you Lobo...It has helped a lot..

Answer (score 1):

Consider the code below, the constructor is overloaded and can be called either with...

```
new Tester();
```

or

```
new Tester("Hello world!");
```

These would both be valid in the given class

```
class Tester {
    public Tester() {

    }

    public Tester(String overloaded) {
        System.out.println(overloaded);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you David for the example