# What lines should be uncommented and why, inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a code-snippet, and I should determine what line I should un-comment so it will compile.

**Question:** Why only lines 9,13 and 10,14 works? Why wont 9,14 work for example? I'm a bit confused. help is highly appreciated! **(Btw, the options are only un-commenting two lines of code)**

```
1. // Question 3.1
2. class Car {
3.  private Car() { }
4.  protected Car(int x) { }
5. }
6. public class MG extends Car {
7.   // MG(int x) { }
8.   // MG(int x) { super(); }
9.   // MG(int x) { super(x); }
10.  // private MG(int x) { super(x); }
11.  // MG() { }
12.  // MG() { this(); }
13.  // MG() { this(6); }
14.  // MG() { super(7); }
15.  public static void main(String[] args) {
16.    new MG(7);
17.    new MG();
18. } }
```

I believe the lack of understand comes from not enough familiarity of private constructor and protected access modifier, so I'm reading on that and I will also continue trying figuring it out.

Edit: Well I almost got it now, first of all line 8 cant be called so options with 8 and 11-14 are gone. line 7 - why can't it be called for e.g. with line 11? I believe MG(){} will be called but first the private car() has to be called, error. with line 12 not possible, because than I need line 11, with line 13 no idea why, with line 14 no idea why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote it on Ideone, because i was pretty sure that line 9 and 14 should work and they do!

Check it here (code)

The only important thing to remember in this example is, that if you do not invoke parent constructor, Java will invoke it in that manner "super()". Since your parent class non-parameter constructor is private, it won't compile.

That's why lines 7,8,11 are plain wrong.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks Rijuk. I didn't know that super() will be called

Comment: Anyways, I believe I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with coding :)

Answer (score 1):

**Inheritance**

Subclass by default get the access of all parent class methods, variables, constructor.

When you are going to create object of child class  then (jvm calls zero parameter constructor implicitly)first parent class constructor executed and then child class constructor.

In your case you are calling super class constructor explicitly.

Use print statement in constructor you will get clear idea ...

Comment: Yes I got it now Navnath. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

First of all Few things to notice:

**First get some idea about access modifiers:**

[image]

**About private constructor:**

prevent subclassing (extending). If you make only a private constructor(**only** have one constructor), no class can extend your class, because it can't call the `super()` constructor. [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816123/can-a-constructor-in-java-be-private)

**And little bit about constructor:**

- Constructors are never inherited - they are specific to the class in
  which they are defined.
- If no constructor implemented, default constructor will added by the
  compiler implicitly.
- In subclasses did not call the `super()` compiler automatically add those to all the constructors.
- When a new object that is a subclass is constructed, the constructor
  for the superclass is always called first.
- Constructor invocation maybe implicit or explicit.

  - explicit call to a constructor of superclass: `super()` - has to be the first statement in the subclass constructor.

**Without any constructor in `MG`:**

In this line `public class MG extends Car {` eclipse show error:

> Implicit super constructor `Car()` is not visible for default
>   constructor. Must define an explicit constructor.

Because of inheritance you need to pass values to parent class constructor.

And for this `new MG(7);`:

> The constructor MG(int) is undefined

Because you donot have any parameterized constructor in `MG` class.

**UPDATE:**

*You said in your question you only want to know about line number 7, 11, 12, 13 and 14. But I will answer for all the lines. Then others who looking for answer also can understand*

**If you uncomment line number 7:**

When we create an object of a child class always the constructor of the parent get completed and the constructor of the child runs later.

When you run the program, First in the main method `new MG(7);` object looking for matching constructor in the `MG`, which is `MG(int x) {}`. Inside this has `super()` which is compiler added one. Then compiler look for default constructor in parent class, It cannot find since default constructor is `private`.

To fix this: `MG(int x) {super(x);}`

**If you uncomment line number 8:**

When you run the program, First in the main method `new MG(7);` object looking for matching constructor in the `MG`, which is found.

```
MG(int x) {super()}
```

If you added `super()` or not compiler will add this. There is no different between these two:

```
MG(int x) {}
MG(int x) {super()}
```

**If you uncomment line number 9:**

This line is fine(no errors). First compiler looking for constructor(`MG(int x) { super(x); }` for object(`new MG(7);`). Then inside the constructor have called `super(x)` which is have one argument and it is match with the parent class constructor. As I mentioned before, parent class constructor execute first, Then child class constructor execute.

**If you uncomment line number 10:**

```
private MG(int x) { super(x); }
```

Access modifier is not affected because this class is a subclass and it is not a parent class for any class. And we can create object from calling `private` constructor. [read more about private constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816123/can-a-constructor-in-java-be-private).

**If you uncomment line number 11:**

```
MG() { }
```

It is match with the `new MG();` object. Compiler have added `super()` but no matching constructor found in the parent class.

**If you uncomment line number 12:**

```
MG() { this(); }
```

First, **lets look at what is `this()`:**

- `this` can be used inside the Method or constructor of Class.
- `this` works as a reference to the current Object whose Method or
  constructor is being invoked.
- The this keyword can be used to refer to any member of the current
  object from within an instance Method or a constructor.
- `this()` keyword can be used inside the constructor to call another
  overloaded constructor in the same Class.
- This is also called the Explicit Constructor Invocation.
- And `this()` and `super()` both cannot use in one constructor.

So this line is unnecessary because you don't have any other `MG()` constructors. [learn more about `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182153/constructor-overloading-in-java-best-practice).

**If you uncomment line number 13:**

```
MG() { this(6); }
```

This is also unnecessary or cannot be called unless you have another `MG()` constructor. If you do like this:

```
MG(){
    this(6);
}
MG(int x){
    super(x);
}
```

What happen here is when you run the program `new MG();` object find the default constructor and in it call the parameterized constructor(`MG(int x){}`). Then in the this constructor take the value and send it to the parent class.

**If you uncomment line number 14:**

```
MG() { super(7); }
```

`new MG();` is matched with the costructor and in it you have passed value `7` to the parent class parameterized constructor.

Done.

Comment: None of the classes are private. They have private constructors.