# My constructor is not giving the desired output

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor

```
    package rups;

    public class vipcustomer{


    private String name;
    private int creditlimit;
    private String emailid;

    public vipcustomer(){
    this("Rupali", 5000, "rupalisingh@gmial.com");
    System.out.println("Constructer with default values");
    }

    public vipcustomer(int creditlimit, String emailid) {
        this("Rups", creditlimit, emailid);
        this.creditlimit = creditlimit;
        this.emailid = emailid;
        System.out.println("Constructor with 1 default values");
    }

    public vipcustomer(String name, int creditlimit, String emailid) {
        this.name = name;
        this.creditlimit = creditlimit;
        this.emailid = emailid;
        System.out.println("Constructer with no default values");
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCreditlimit() {
        return creditlimit;
    }

    public String getEmailid() {
        return emailid;
    }
    }

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            new vipcustomer();
            new vipcustomer(5000, "sdhoahfsdh");
            new vipcustomer("Rups", 7000, "dfksjdfsjdfa");


    }
    }
```

output

```
Constructer with no default values
Constructor with 1 default values
Constructer with no default values
```

Here the 1st constructor should give output as "Constructor with default values" but it is not so. What am i doing wrong?please help.

Comment: its says "Constructor with no default value". But when I am calling the default constructor it should print "Constructor with default values".

Comment: What do you think `this(...)` is doing?

Comment: Side note: why do you set fields doubly? Why the redundant code in this `public vipcustomer(int creditlimit, String emailid) {` constructor. The call to `this` already sets fields for you.

Comment: ohhh....ok. So no need to use this. again for second constructor.

Comment: @RupaliSingh Read this: [Constructor Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182153/constructor-overloading-in-java-best-practice)

Answer (score 5):

From within a constructor, you can use the `this` keyword to call another constructor in the same class. Doing so is called an **explicit constructor invocation**.

---

Let's analyse your code, there are three constructors :

```
public vipcustomer()//------------------------------------------------(C1)
public vipcustomer(int creditlimit, String emailid)//-----------------(C2)
public vipcustomer(String name, int creditlimit, String emailid)//----(C3)
```

so when you use :

```
new vipcustomer();
```

It call this constructor :

```
public vipcustomer() {
    this("Rupali", 5000, "rupalisingh@gmial.com");
    System.out.println("Constructer with default values");
}
```

But note `this("Rupali", 5000, "rupalisingh@gmial.com");` It call the the `C3` when `C3` finish it print :

```
Constructor with no default values
```

for that the first output is :

```
Constructor with no default values
```

**then**

```
Constructor with default values
```

---

The same for the other constructors.

**The `this()` function calls overloaded constructors according to the arguments list.**

Take a look at this :

- [Using this with a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score 1):

Cause for your wrong output is following default constructor.

```
public vipcustomer(){
    this("Rupali", 5000, "rupalisingh@gmial.com"); // Will call 3 argument constructor
    System.out.println("Constructer with default values");
}
```

Within the default constructor (No argument constructor) you have called

```
this("Rupali", 5000, "rupalisingh@gmial.com");
```

That means it will call the constuctor that you have provided with 3 arguments.

```
public vipcustomer(String name, int creditlimit, String emailid) {...}
```

---

**This keyword**

The `this` keyword has 2 meanings. In the constructor, `this(...)` (like method call) act as a call for the constructors. The compiler decides which constructor to call based on the **number arguments** and **types of the arguments** of the provided constructors.

In other case `this` keyword use as a reference.