# (this is my first program ) java invalid method declaration; return type required

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
public class Employee {

   public String name;

   private double salary;

   public Employee (String empName) {
      name = empName;
   }
   public  lary(double empSal) {
      salary = empSal;
   }

   public void printEmp() {
      System.out.println("name  : " + name );
      System.out.println("salary :" + salary);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Employee empOne = new Employee("Ransika");
     lary emptwo = new lary(1000);
      empOne.printEmp();
      emptwo.printEmp();
   }
}
```

Employee.java:16: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
   public  lary(double empSal). can number  cannot be defined as above.

Comment: methods need a return type

Comment: I presume you had `public void setSalary`, and for some reason you deleted `void setSa` from it, and ended up with nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption looking at your main method is that you want to create 2 employees. One with a name and one with a salary. For that you can use overloading (read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182153/constructor-overloading-in-java-best-practice?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)).

If you want a seperate class for lary then you should create that outside the Employee class. Below you can find an example overloading the class like I'm assuming you want to do.

Overloading example:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Employee {

   public String name;

   private double salary;

   public Employee (String empName) {
      name = empName;
   }
   public Employee(double empSal) {
      salary = empSal;
   }

   public void printEmp() {
      System.out.println("name  : " + name );
      System.out.println("salary :" + salary);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Employee empOne = new Employee("Ransika");
      Employee emptwo = new Employee(1000);
      empOne.printEmp();
      emptwo.printEmp();
   }
}
```

Comment: You make assumptions about what the OP is trying to do, and you completely avoid explaining what the actual problem is.. so not sure how this answer is supposed to be useful for the OP

Comment: @musefan he is actually right, you can check main method of OP's code

Comment: @Hatik: Nah... "lary" doesn't mean anything so it definitely isn't intentional. Best to clarify with OP rather than guess

Comment: @musefan I change the description a bit hopefully it's a bit more clear for the OP then.