# passing object into constructor Java

Tags: java

i have a class constructor

```
public Knapsack(Item[] items){
       // to do
      }
```

Then I have and Item class that takes two arguments string and int.
so for example

```
Knapsack k = new Item("Pen", 15);
```

when this object is passed into my constructor in other class how do I can use only single arguments such as **"PEN"**  and int **15**

Comment: You can create multiple constructors for the same class and initialise the different behaviour in each constructor. This is generally called [overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1182153/10400050)

Comment: That object can't be passed. It needs to be in an array

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an array to constructor like this:

`Knapsack k = new Knapsack(new Item[]{new Item("Pen", 15)});`

Also, if you want to pass literal values to Knapsack class and not the Item's array, then you can apply the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java) here.

Answer (score 0):

You need an array of items, as the constructor says. A Knapsack cannot be assigned to an Item

For example

```
Item[] items = new Item[1];
items[0] = new Item("Pen", 15);

Knapsack k = new Knapsack(items);
```

Alternatively, you could define a builder method to the Knapsack

```
public Knapsack(){
   // to do
}

public Knapsack withItem(String name, int amount) {
    Item i = new Item(name, amount);
    // to do: add to the Knapsack 
    return this;
}
```

Then you would have

```
Knapsack k = new Knapsack().withItem("Pen", 15);
```

And you can chain multiple `withItem` calls together

Comment: yes this is exactly how to use this but then when is passed string and int I want in my new class use only that string and int separately. But it is in array right? so k[0] = pen and k[1] = 15 right?

Comment: No, `k` is not an array, but let's assume it were, then `k.get(0)` would return an Item object, again, not an array, and you would do `k.get(0).getName()`